# write flat sign in lyrics in Gregorio

Tags: gregorio

I want to write B-flat3 underneath a lyric so the singer knows the absolute pitch to start on.

```
My[Start on B-flat3](abc) Ly(def)rics(gh)
```

But, I want the symbol for the flat.  Is that possible?

Comment: Does `\flat` work?

Comment: no.  just comes out with the \.

Comment: i found something...  if you use <v>♭</v>, it works outside the [ ], but not inside.  in other words, it works on the lyrics line but not on the line below it.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a way to do this, then would be to use a translation line. (There is no way to write a second line of words properly, because it’s very hard to code, but it’s a feature that’s in high demand.)

`Lyrics[translation](abc)` would be the way to write it in the gabc file. But, are you able to put things in  tags?

Use `\gresettranslationcentering{center}` in the tex file to keep it on the same line.

This said, this is where an MWE is helpful (and in your case, with some details: giving an absolute pitch is unusual in Gregorian performance, but it’s possible that you’re not engraving a Gregorian score but some other form of early music.)